# CGBitmapInfo swift what's new?

Tags: xcode, bitmap, swift

Just trying to use:

```
    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
        self.bounds.width as UInt,
        self.bounds.height as UInt,
        8,
        nil,
        CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big)
```

But it says that `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big` is unresolved identifier. But I found many examples like this in stackoverflow, but for objectiveC. Q: How to init/get CGBitmapInfo

The right syntax:

```
   var context:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
        UInt(self.bounds.width),
        UInt(self.bounds.height),
        8,
        0,
        CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, this should be `CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big`. You can pass it as just `.ByteOrder32Big` because the type `CGBitmapInfo` is already known.

In general, ObjC/CoreFoundation enums in the form TypeValue or kTypeValue are Type.Value in Swift.

You're passing `nil` as `bytesPerRow`. I think you meant `0` here. `nil` is not the same thing (though it's probably working for you in ObjC).